# Sonar Lint Ruleset files: Gitignore?

Tags: visual-studio, sonarqube, gitignore

I installed SonarLint and hooked it up to our server in Visual Studio, and when I did `git status` it showed all these net `.ruleset` files. Should I put this extension in the `.gitignore` file or add them to the repo?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

TLDR; Commit them to share them with your team.

.ruleset files are collections of rules and their status (enabled, disabled, severity). When you bind your solution to SonarQube two things happen:

a. analyzers are installed to your projects as nuget packages (this is how .net analyzers work btw, you install them just like a reference). There is no other way to install analyzers and this is why your csproj are dirtied.

b. ruleset files are created to match the quality profile from the SQ server (the analyzers usually enable all their rules, but the SonarQube quality profile disables some of them and assigns different severities).

If you commit the changes, when your colleagues do a `git pull` all they have to do is build and the analyzer nuget packages will be installed. So they don't need to have the SonarLint plugin installed.

Comment: Thanks! The best part of this is probably that the goons who never log in to our SQ server will be exposed to the analysis, and the other team members who never read the instructions won't have to find their SQ token to bind it.

Comment: Not a good Idea at all. These rules change often, more often if you apply Narrowing to legacy code. This files should be volatile and synchronized time to time.

Comment: @Fals - all the files or just the ruleset files?

Comment: @StingyJack only the rule files.